# UI Framework/Toolkit for Web Applications

Tags: user-interface, twitter-bootstrap, css-frameworks, web-application-design

Are there any UI Toolkits/Frameworks that can be used for a web application like Bootstrap, from Twitter(http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)?

I am currently upgrading an old ASP line of business application and I would like to use a common framework to handle grids, alert messages, forms, etc. I am very familiar with jQuery UI, but it is not as complete as I would like it to be. My main concern is I just want a consistent UI for the application that other developers can use that are not too design-savy.
Also, I would like the application to behave consistently throughout the application.

I don't need a framework for the server-side as I am using ASP.NET MVC. By the way, I am using both jQuery and jQuery UI, but I am looking for something that can fill in the missing blanks.

Comment: I actually have been using Bootstrap, from Twitter with jQuery UI and it seems to work out really well.

Comment: What is keeping you from using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 2):

We have tried so many different options, the most robust and flexible solution remains jQuery and jQuery UI. There are tons of people writing widgets for it, and it is compatible with a lot of technology unlike some other frameworks which limit you, precisely because it is simple and light weight.

What exactly is your reservation with jQuery?

The options we have tried are Google Web Toolkit, Ext-JS and Prototype, none as nice and easy as jQuery.

Comment: I actually use both jQuery and jQuery UI quite extensively, but I am looking for a framework just for the UI that covers basic things like alert messages, form look-and-feel, etc. What I have found is developers would create their own CSS classes that would only get used once and the application would end up with a lot of duplicate CSS. So far, I am actually liking bootstrap, because it covers most of the basic cases out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

We are using [Telerik Extensions for MVC](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc) for all the interactions that we have in our web applications and we are very pleased with it. We use their stylesheets to style our form inputs and buttons. The stylesheet are easily editable if you want to change the theme.

btw, it use jQuery underneath.